# Job for openvpn@server.service failed

Tags: centos, openvpn, radius

here is the problem during starting the OpenVPN service.. Just after command

```
systemctl start openvpn@server.service
```

terminal shows message:

```
Job for openvpn@server.service failed. See 'systemctl status
openvpn@server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

What did I do wrong? Could you help me, please?

Comment: So when you did as the message said and checked the service status and the logs, what did they say? [edit] your question and show us.